# Is a parametric subvariety singular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a parametric subvariety $V^k$ of $A^{2n}$ (so, given by $2n$ polynomials in in $k$ variables). The question is: how does one tell whether $V^n$ intersects itself? In the $k=1$ case, there is a single parameter, and if a curve is given by $\mathbf{f}(t)=(f_1(t), \dotsc, f_n(t),$ we need to check whether $$\frac{\mathbf{f}(t)- \mathbf{f}(s)}{s-t}=0$$ has any solutions, which is a simple elimination problem. However, for $k>1,$ the expedient of dividing by $s-t$ is not available, so how does one eliminate the stupid $s=t$ solutions?

**Remark** On some reflection, given a putative solution, one can compute the tangent spaces at the two parameter values, and check that the intersection has the proper rank (smaller than $k$ or $2k-n$ if one wants the intersection to be transversal. This is purely algebraic, but involves computing many minors, so is (more than) a little horrible. Surely there is a better way...